# How can I let Angular2 child components access the parents SCSS styles?

Tags: angular, components, encapsulation

I have an `app.module.ts` which includes a partial SCSS file called `_colors.scss`. This file contained named colors like:

`$white: #FFFFFF`

and many more.

Here is the component:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', // <my-app></my-app>
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  styles: [ require('./app.component.imports.scss')],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  url = 'https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack';

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    // Do something with api
  }
}
```

Inside `./app.component.imports.scss` is `@import "../style/app.scss";` which has `@import "../style/global-vars/_colors.scss"` inside of it.

When I load up another route I am getting a compilation error from Jetpack and in the browser console:

```
VM3358:1 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: 
  color: $sharp-blue;
        ^
      Undefined variable: "$sharp-blue".
      in /Users/username/Local Repo/project/retail-ui/src/style/app.scss (line 35, column 10)
```

After doing some reading on style encapsulation I would have thought by setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` this style would be available in all children components but that is not the case?

How can I get the `_colors.scss` partial to load and be available in my child components?

Comment: It has nothing to do with encapsulation. Component's SCSS needs to access a variable. Variables don't exist in CSS output. Hence SCSS file that contains a variable should be imported in every file that uses a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has rarely to do with the view encapsulation, it´s more a sass related topic. The view encapsulation only simulates the shadow doms styling behaviour.

Since the entries in the styles array represent a new file each, every sass file needs to import the `_colors.scss` on its own.

Comment: This seems to be correct, however it doesn't "solve" the problem of being able to universally include styles.

Comment: If you need global styles for your whole application, you could just add a normal stylesheet in your index.html or similar. Your sass variables can´t be accessible out of their context.